# Coding Code Blocks/ ASCII Tree structures from text in js

Tags: javascript, data-structures, tree, treeview, vscode-extensions

Im kind of a beginner in programming and i decided to try and create a vscode extension that i can use. im trying to create a tree structure like this that works when typing in vscode txt files. [image: Tree Structure]

In this vscode example picture it shows what im trying to accomplish.

**I want to be able to write text in the vscode text editor and have it be the root/top/head node like Function is in the screenshots... then after typing the root text and clicking enter or any keyboard command, it should  create a child and draw the line connecting the root to the child onto the vscode text editor in real time like the screenshot.**

So in normal words. i want to be able to name my root node by simply typing in the text editor, then clicking enter to start naming a new child while automatically drawing/linking them from root to children to leaf's etc.

Im pretty sure i can figure out the logic and structuring on my own but i have no idea how im to link the root and child nodes with lines in real time.

any ideas?

[image: VSCODE EXAMPLE]